Nx run-many show changes of remote app from shell app
I have microfrontend application and I use Nx to manage it. I want to work on remote app from the view of shell (host) app. When I run nx run-many --target=serve --projects=host,remote-app1, go to localhost of the host app,  do changes in remote-app1 , in console I can see some changes have been made but they are not painted on the screen.

Is it possible to get this kind of behaviour work?
I use Nx 18.2.0.
